# Macros in package

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

As I understood, SystemVerilog does not support macros definition in the package.
And if you want to implement your own macros for UVM, than you should write them in separate file and include that file in the top, similar to including "uvm_macros.svh" file.

Can someone please confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

Macros definitions and other compiler directives are processed as part of a compilation unit before any other SystemVerilog syntax gets recognized. So the text for a macro deffintion might appear within the text that defines a package, but the definition is valid for any source code that appears after it in the compilation unit, and has no relevance to any scope defined in SystemVerilog. So yes, you do want to put your macros in a separate file and include them in any compilation unit that wants to use them.

Please see:

https://verificationacademy.com/forums/ovm/do-you-include-or-import#reply-35286